# Probability values of arbitrary precision in SymPy

Tags: python, probability, sympy, arbitrary-precision, mpmath

I am trying to compute some simple probabilities in Sympy, but I keep getting numerical errors.  How could I change this code to use arbitrary precision in mpmath?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import Binomial, density, P
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 1000
n = 128

X = Binomial('X', n, 1/2, succ=1, fail=0)

for t in range (n+1):
    print(t, P(X<t))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `Rational`?

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.stats import Binomial, density, P
>>> n = 128
>>> X = Binomial('X', n, Rational(1,2), succ=1, fail=0)
>>> for t in range(n+1):
...     print(t, P(X<t))
```

produces the following output:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(2, 129/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(3, 8257/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(4, 349633/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(5, 11017633/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(6, 275584033/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(7, 5699195233/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(8, 100224990433/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(9, 1529927642833/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(10, 20592629674833/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(11, 247438783855633/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(12, 2680879346886033/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(13, 26406924836432433/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(14, 238116253820077233/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(15, 1977157170471445233/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(16, 15193868137021842033/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(17, 108536889338284019433/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(18, 723502676076011305833/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(19, 4515791694291996238633/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(20, 26471149168174014270633/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(21, 146127847400831012545033/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(22, 761505152597352717956233/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(23, 3754476591507708285183433/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(24, 17548171049094564377621833/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(25, 77895584301037059782039833/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(26, 328940823429117840664418713/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(27, 1323466193821130164929227353/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(28, 5080562037524287834374059993/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(29, 18632943473739249427728634873/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(30, 65365293253790841128951306873/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(31, 219582047527961093742986124473/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(32, 707105980394692860071225225273/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(33, 2184912901896973526753699999573/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(34, 6483987582630880920739081161173/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(35, 18496108014093269227462940289173/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(36, 50757231458592254965521304804373/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(37, 134098467023547968122172079801973/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(38, 341325323022897308944114547363573/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(39, 837579109758181256701924140734773/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(40, 1982780156070374982296869356206773/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(41, 4530852484115006021745622460631973/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(42, 9999885773576653130806360831105573/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(43, 21328597587461493571003604598515173/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(44, 43986021215231174451398092133334373/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(45, 87756044132513512515796533961962373/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(46, 169460086911440543569340292042067973/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(47, 316882598882113230035517072925736773/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(48, 574087832533074087274378690637669573/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(49, 1008121664319070533864957670526556173/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(50, 1716748328459472895645494780549228173/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(51, 2836378457801308627258743414385049933/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(52, 4548753949735880922667241324957483213/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(53, 7084386889715920667791363230997432493/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(54, 10720388841385411623063688983054718253/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(55, 15770391552037482394275252527578726253/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(56, 22564940653642086704632628932938300653/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(57, 31422120732519517323491351747067745853/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(58, 42610137674259429684155001617547045053/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(59, 56305813585699667229105331631409635453/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(60, 72554920599272830418029451986839827453/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(61, 91241393664881968085292190395584548253/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(62, 112072216098675760894699833211890138653/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(63, 134582943567452924091962931094026825053/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(64, 158165610439505190298619509827693829853/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(65, 182116756481433273164755097604074381603/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(66, 205699423353485539371411676337741386403/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(67, 228210150822262702568674774219878072803/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(68, 249040973256056495378082417036183663203/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(69, 267727446321665633045345155444928384003/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(70, 283976553335238796234269275800358576003/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(71, 297672229246679033779219605814221166403/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(72, 308860246188418946139883255684700465603/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(73, 317717426267296376758741978498829910803/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(74, 324511975368900981069099354904189485203/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(75, 329561978079553051840310918448713493203/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(76, 333197980031222542795583244200770778963/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(77, 335733612971202582540707366106810728243/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(78, 337445988463137154836115864017383161523/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(79, 338565618592478990567729112651218983283/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(80, 339274245256619392929509649761241655283/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(81, 339708279088405389376100228741130541883/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(82, 339965484322056350233339090358842474683/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(83, 340112906834027022919805267139726143483/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(84, 340194610876805949950858810897806249083/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(85, 340238380899723232288923209339634877083/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(86, 340261038323351001969803603827169696283/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(87, 340272367035164886810243801070937105883/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(88, 340277836068454348457352861809307579483/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(89, 340280384140782393088392310562412004683/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(90, 340281529341828705282117905507627476683/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(91, 340282025595615440566065663317220847883/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(92, 340282232822471439915406485259688409483/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(93, 340282316163707004871119641910463407083/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(94, 340282348424830449370105379968827922283/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(95, 340282360436950880832493686692687050283/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(96, 340282364736025561566401080678068211883/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(97, 340282366213832483068681747360542986183/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(98, 340282366701356415935413513688782086983/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(99, 340282366855573170209583766302816904583/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(100, 340282366902305519989635358004039576583/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(101, 340282366915857901425850319597394151463/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(102, 340282366919614997269553477266838984103/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(103, 340282366920609522639945489591103792743/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(104, 340282366920860567879073570371986171623/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(105, 340282366920920915292325512867390589623/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(106, 340282366920934708986783099723483028023/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(107, 340282366920937701958222010079050255223/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(108, 340282366920938317335527206600755666423/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(109, 340282366920938436992225439257753940823/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(110, 340282366920938458947582913139771972823/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(111, 340282366920938462739871931355756905623/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(112, 340282366920938463354837718093484192023/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(113, 340282366920938463448180739294746369423/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(114, 340282366920938463461397450261296766223/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(115, 340282366920938463463136491177948134223/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(116, 340282366920938463463348200506931779023/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(117, 340282366920938463463371926552421325423/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(118, 340282366920938463463374359992984355823/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(119, 340282366920938463463374586839138536623/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(120, 340282366920938463463374605901840568623/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(121, 340282366920938463463374607331543221023/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(122, 340282366920938463463374607426069016223/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(123, 340282366920938463463374607431492627423/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(124, 340282366920938463463374607431757193823/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(125, 340282366920938463463374607431767861823/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(126, 340282366920938463463374607431768203199/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(127, 340282366920938463463374607431768211327/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
(128, 340282366920938463463374607431768211455/340282366920938463463374607431768211456)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rodrigo.  Another error I found is that I was using n (instead of n-1), as sympy binomial starts from 0, the P was wrong...